# How to add an object parameter into a string post api curl?

Tags: php, api, object, curl

Can someone help me to fix this issue, i need to provide an object type parameter to my code to fetch data using shopee API.

here is my code

```
$partner_key = "c423d22ccf4a8f1ca3cf9f49d7995f7d2a11e58b6a57036bd8385e8d978b4db2";
        $partner_id = 2003151;
        $shop_id = 30334567;
        $ordersn = "";
        $username = "info@pollandhopia.com";
        $password = "101382qpqeiw";
        $datenow = time();
        $parcel->item_id = 455371271;
        $parcel->variation_id = 0;
        $parcel->order_item_id = 455371271;
        $parcel->promotion_group_id = 0;
 

        $object = json_encode($parcel);

        $post = '{
            "shopid": '.$shop_id.',

            "ordersn": "220506EWDX3UXW",

            "partner_id": '.$partner_id.',

            "timestamp": '.$datenow.',

            "parcels": '.$parcel.'
        }';

        $url = "https://partner.shopeemobile.com/api/v1/orders/split";



        //Generate a signature base string for POST
        $base_string = $url."|".$post;


        //Generate a unique signature
        $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $base_string, $partner_key);

        
        #echo $signature.'----'.$datenow.'-'.$object;exit;
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization:".$signature, "Content-Type: application/json"));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        $result = json_decode($result);

        curl_close($ch);
```

Then the documentation params is here

[image]

Here is my error:

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
> Type: Error
> Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: Thank you for sharing your credentials! Do `json_encode` with your `$post` instead of manually creating possibly faulty json. How you use `$result`? Most likely you try to do `echo $result` later on and that throws error

Comment: $result will contain the data from the API i will echo its value to check if its correct.
ok i will try doing the json_encode inside my post, Thanks!